# How to reload a jasper report repeatedly within every one minute

Tags: jasperserver

I use a jasper report as my dashboard on Jasper Server 6.4.2 version.on that report, I have to display current time with live updates without reloading the report ***manually***.
I tried to schedule the report and set as output options as **Overwrite Files** and it's not worked.

***Basically,I want to reload a report when it already opened and displayed withing every given time period repeatedly until I close the report. How can I do this?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way by myself.

Go to ***ViewReport.jsp*** on jasper server installation files. (When a report loads,this page executes)

Then add below code for it.(Actually we use java script to do this.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var url = window.location.href; //take current tab url
 var dash = 'http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flo...';

 if(url == dash ){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);
 }
</script>
```

**url** is the current display report URL.

**dash** is the URL that we want to refresh. otherwise all the reports will be refresh within every 5 seconds.

**5000** is time gap want to refresh.

***restart the jasper server.***

that's it..